# How many times based on two different percentages

Tags: statistics, percentages

Following is a percentage of a total population.

X: 58%

Y: 22%

Z: 20%

In Garden:

X: 30%

Y: 27%

Z: 43%

I want to calculate How many times Y is more likely in the Garden? The answer will be like this. Y is 6 times more likely in garden than X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are looking for (27/22) / (30/58) => 2.37

Members of Y seem 2.37 times more likely to visit the Garden, than members of X.